# using cmake to make header files descendants of the project's source directory

Tags: c++, cmake

As in [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Names_and_Order_of_Includes) is mentioned all of a project's header files should be listed as descendants of the project's source directory without use of UNIX directory shortcuts . (the current directory) or .. (the parent directory). How can I do that in my project that is shortly described below.

My project directory hierarchy is like this:

- GraphicsEngine

  - header_files.h
  - source_files.cc
  - CMakeLists.txt (1)
  - Light

    - CMakeLists.txt (2)
    - header_files.h
    - source_files.cc
  - Camera

    - CMakeLists.txt (3)
    - header_files.h
    - source_files.cc
  - Core

    - CMakeLists.txt (4)
    - header_files.h
    - source_files.cc

These are contents of CMakeLists.txt files:

CMakeLists.txt (1)

```
add_library(GraphicsEngineLib source_files.cc)
target_link_libraries(GraphicsEngineLib LightLib CameraLib CoreLib)
add_subdirectory(Light)
add_subdirectory(Camera)
add_subdirectory(Core)
```

CMakeLists.txt (2)

```
add_library(LightLib source_files.cc)
```

CMakeLists.txt (3)

```
add_library(CameraLib source_files.cc)
```

CMakeLists.txt (4)

```
add_library(CoreLib source_files.cc)
```

Now when for example I want to include header files from Camera folder in to files in Core folder, I have to use ../Camera/header_file.h but I want to use GraphicsEngine/Camera/header_file.h. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done in the past is to set this in the top level `CMakeLists.txt` (which should be in your `GraphicsEngine` directory):

```
SET(PROJECT_ROOT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  ${PROJECT_ROOT}
)
```

where according to [this](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables), `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` is

> this is the directory where the currently processed CMakeLists.txt is located in

Note that by defining `Project_Root` in this way, your `GraphicsEngine` project can also `#include` headers from *sister* projects to `GraphicsEngine`.

Hope this helps.